# Phantom.js with Ubuntu 11.04x64/MediaTemple - Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-11.04, phantomjs, mediatemple

I'm trying to use Phantom.js 1.7 on Ubuntu 11.04 x64. The hosting is mediatemple.
When I do "./phantomjs" I get this -

PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/CrashReporting and file a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/entry with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/7dac25de-0ce0-d719-2e631f5b-593eb037.dmp
Segmentation fault

(already filed a bug report - https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=860&thanks=860&ts=1352298059

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segmentation fault occurs when a process tries to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address.

This means that when you are trying to start phantomjs, you could maybe don't have enough RAM on the server you are renting from them.

I would try increasing your RAM so that your process has more memory to access.

---

**EDIT** when l run phantomjs on linux ubuntu 12.04 machine, from checking its memory usage, it averages across all the processes is creates, about 0.7GB - 1.1GB of RAM usage.

Answer (score 1):

try to add smth like this :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
//...
page.settings = { 
  // userAgent: agent, 
  loadImages: false//, 
  // localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true, 
  // javascriptEnabled: true,
  // loadPlugins: false 
};
page.open(page.address, function (status) {
//...
```

It helps me :)